# How to translate Boolean field labels?

Tags: 7, entities, i18n-l10n

I have created Boolean fields. I have set values 0/1 in database and No/Yes as labels to display in UI. But I cannot translate these labels. I have translated strings "Yes" and "No" using UI on link admin/config/regional/translate/translate but it does not work for field labels.

Can anybody help?

thanks Tomas

Answer (score 4):

I'm relatively new to Drupal but I've had the same problem recently and this is how I solved it:

- install the [i18n module](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) and enable the **"field translation"** sub-module (and its dependencies).
- in the boolean field settings (`admin/structure/types/manage/[your-content-type]/fields` and click the edit link next to the field) make sure you have specified a value for the **On** and **Off** states (e.g. Yes/No).
- then on the same page (boolean field settings), use the **translate** tab (on top of the page) and click "translate" for each language you need:
- under the **Field instance** tab, you can translate the label for the field.
- under the **Field settings** tab, you can translate the values for the On/Off states.
- lastly (and this is perhaps the less obvious step), go to **manage display** (for your content type), and as **"format"** for you boolean field, choose **"Default translated"** instead of "Default".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think steps 3-6 aren’t needed.

Comment: This procedure works, but it has to be repeated for every Bool field you want to translate.

Answer (score 0):

Try in field management
Allowed values PHP code

```
return array(
  0 => t('No'),
  1 => t('Yes'),
);
```